# Making more simple function jquery?

Tags: jquery, function, autocomplete

I have few autocomplete on my page, but i have a problem, everything is working ok, but the problem is that i dont know how may #ID i will have, maybe i can make a function and make some array with ID that way i can easy maintain the code, this is whta i have for now?

```
  $('#autocomplete-1').autocomplete({
            source: autocompleteDataSource,
            minLength: 3,
            delay: 800,
            appendTo: '#auto-complete-1',
            select: autocompleteOnSelect,
            open: function () {
                setTimeout(function () { $("#ui-id-1").show(); }, 100);
            },
            response: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                    $(this).val("No results found");
                } else {
                    $(this).empty();
                }
            }
        });
        $('#autocomplete-2').autocomplete({
            source: autocompleteDataSource,
            minLength: 3,
            delay: 800,
            appendTo: '#auto-complete-2',
            select: autocompleteOnSelect,
            open: function () {
                setTimeout(function () { $("#ui-id-2").show(); }, 100);
            },
            response: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                    $(this).val("No results found");
                } else {
                    $(this).empty();
                }
            }
        });
        $('#autocomplete-3').autocomplete({
            source: autocompleteDataSource,
            minLength: 3,
            delay: 800,
            appendTo: '#auto-complete-3',
            select: autocompleteOnSelect,
            open: function () {
                setTimeout(function () { $("#ui-id-3").show(); }, 100);
            },
            response: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                    $(this).val("No results found");
                } else {
                    $(this).empty();
                }
            }
        });
```

Need to make all ID in array and then loop into function?

Comment: what you actually want, simplfying the jquery function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arr = $('[id^=autocomplete-]');

$.each(arr, function(index, obj){
     $('#autocomplete-' + (index+1)).autocomplete({
        source: autocompleteDataSource,
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 800,
        appendTo: '#autocomplete-' + (index+1),
        select: autocompleteOnSelect,
        open: function () {
            setTimeout(function () { $('#ui-id-' + (index+1)).show(); }, 100);
        },
        response: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                $(this).val("No results found");
            } else {
                $(this).empty();
            }
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Only problem with append

Comment: @Gorostas sorry my bad I missed that one. It's fixed now :)

Comment: This is great mate, txanks, any luck maybe to make array dinamicaly get all autocolemte and ud and make array that if I add new autocomplete on page will work great

Comment: @Gorostas I have changed the code,please try again now.

Comment: Nice but this way, if i got the result, autocomplete does not show? I dont know why?

Comment: I don't know how your html is structured but I have created a fiddle [>>>***here***<<<](http://jsfiddle.net/74375fza/) which works when appendTo is removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an empty CSS class (like `.autocomplete {}`) to all your autocomplete elements, you might alter the function like this:

```
    $('.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source: autocompleteDataSource,
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 800,
        appendTo: this.id,
        select: autocompleteOnSelect,
        open: function () {
            setTimeout(function () { $(this). ??? show(); }, 100);
        },
        response: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                $(this).val("No results found");
            } else {
                $(this).empty();
            }
        }
    });
```

You're basically ending up in just one generic function, no need for any ID-array.

Only thing is to identify the subsequent child with ID `#ui-id-2` in a dynamic way, which depends on your layout (wher the "???" are above)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, use a starts with selector:

```
$("[id^='autocomplete-']").autocomplete
rest of it
```

then get the id as

```
var id = $(this).attr("id").split("autocomplete-")[1]
```

then

```
var ui = $("#ui-id-_" + id)
```

which will give you the id. So you don't need to keep an array for reference, you can get the id from the element.

EDIT:

```
$("[id^='autocomplete-']").autocomplete({
        source: autocompleteDataSource,
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 800,
        var id = $(this).attr("id").split("autocomplete-")[1] //gives you the id
        appendTo: '#auto-complete-' + id,
        select: autocompleteOnSelect, 
        open: function () {
            setTimeout(function () { $("#ui-id-" + id).show(); }, 100);
        },
        response: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                $(this).val("No results found");
            } else {
                $(this).empty();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Only problem with append? Can you please write entire function?

Comment: Still i want to append to diferent ID?

Comment: This is making me a problem appendTo: '#auto-complete-1',

Comment: I can not pass to autocomplete var id??

Comment: @artm You declaring and initializing a variable inside the autocomplete setting array :O ???

Comment: Change append to to "#ui-id-" + id

Comment: @ThinkDifferent Yeah, sorry, I wasn't paying attention to that. You get the idea though?

Comment: Imposible to define var in autocomplete

Comment: @Gorostas Yeah, sorry, completely misunderstood the question. Need to read better next time. Better go with ThinkDifferent